# Installing npm peerDependencies in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm, react-router, npm-install, npm-start

After some browsing it is clear people don't want you to install peerDependencies
That however becomes a necessity in a Jenkins CI pipeline.
In my case i have package A and B depending on package C
I want to install, test and build package C first, then A and B.

**The Problem**
I am using react-router-dom.
This requires the components be imported from the same instance and thus it must be a peerDependency to work.

This is however also required during npm test, and because it is a peerDependency it is not installed with
npm install, nor npm ci

All solutions i have found involve setting the peerDependencies as devDependencies.
The problem with that is it breaks in local dev servers

Comment: found any solution to that?

Comment: Also looking for a solution.
calling "npm install somepeerdependency@1.2.3" will change the package-lock so I don't want to do that.